# Pass an argument to -f with cut function in bash?

Tags: bash

I have some trouble in my Bash code.

I would like to use a function who return the part of an array at which talk for example, I have `${TAB[0]}="a" "b" "c"`, I will get:

```sh
echo ${TAB[0]} | cut -d" " -f1 for get "a"
echo ${TAB[0]} | cut -d" " -f2 for get "b"
echo ${TAB[0]} | cut -d" " -f3 for get "c"
```

I use my function `dest` like that:

```sh
function dest(){
   echo $(echo $1 | cut -d" " -f$2)
}
```

And I talk it right here:

```sh
let i=1
while [ ! -z $(dest ${TAB[0]} $i) ]
do
    ${TABUTIL[$i]}=$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")
    echo ${TABUTIL[$i]}
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

Unfornately I get this error:

```sh
cut: option requires an argument — 'f'
```

I don't understand, I is an argument no?

Comment: Why don't you simply `read -a TAB <<< 'a b c'` and then access each item by its index, like `${TAB[0]}`, `${TAB[1]}` etc?

Comment: i tried it in first, but a always get all values in the index of 0. The rest is empty..

Comment: Can you show us the full code and and inputs?

Comment: `dest` is unnecessarily complicated. `dest () { echo "$1" | cut -d" " -f"$2"; }`

Comment: How does `TAB` get set in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function dest(){
   echo $(echo $1 | cut -d" " -f$2)
}
```

Is a useless use of echo and everything is unquoted. Also the `function dest()` is a mix of function declaration available in ksh shell and posix shell, which bash supports both ways. Use just `dest()` to be compatible with all possible shells. In posix shell do:

```
dest() {
    printf "%s\n" "$1" | cut -d" " -f"$2"
}
```

and in bash do:

```
dest() {
    <<<"$1" cut -d" " -f"$2"
}
```

Then you can check if the element is not empty:

```
while [ ! -z "$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")" ]
```

Note that by convention upper case variables are used for variables that get exported.

The line:

```
${TABUTIL[$i]}=$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")
```

is invalid - you can't assign to expansion of a variable. You want:

```
TABUTIL[$i]=$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")
```

to assign to the element of an array.

All together could look like this:

```
dest() {
   <<<"$1" cut -d" " -f$2)
}
i=1
while [ ! -z "$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")" ]
do
    TABUTIL[$i]=$(dest "${TAB[0]}" "$i")
    echo "${TABUTIL[$i]}"
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

But I would suggest to just do:

```
# read the space separated list from TAB into array TABUTIL
IFS=' ' read -r -a TABUTIL <<<"${TAB[0]}"
# print each element of the array TABUTIL on a separate line
printf "%s\n" "${TABUTIL[@]}"
```

for most probably the same effect.

In your question you stated:

```
${TAB[0]}="a" "b" "c"
```

which is invalid - it will try to assign to an array expansion, and then export that value as an environment variable and run a command named `b` with one argument `c`. You meant:

```
TAB[0]='a b c'
```

Which assigns the string `a b c` to element `0` of array `TAB`.

> I don't understand, I is an argument no?

Look at `dest ${TAB[0]} $i` with unquoted arguments. The `${TAB[0]}` expands to `a b c` and `$i` expands to `0` on the first run of the loop. So the call becomes:

```
dest a b c 0
```

So the dest function is passed 4 arguments - and the second argument is `b`, not a number. Depending what is really inside `TAB[0]`, it will make your `cut` fail and  the arguments passed to `dest` function are not what you expect. Rule of a thumb - always, always, always quote your expansions.

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's important to always quote your variables. On the `while` line, if `${TAB[0]}` is an empty string, the `dest` function only receives one argument ($i), so in the function $2 is empty.

All of these quotes are *required*.

```sh
        while [ ! -z "$(dest "${TAB[0]}" $i)" ]
```

And the function should be:

```sh
function dest(){
    echo "$1" | cut -d" " -f$2
}
```

`echo $(...)` is usually not required: just let the command output to stdout.

Comment: Thanks ! i tried and i don't have the error with cut, but i got "
./boite.sh: line 129: =val: command not found
". At that line i have "  ${TABUTIL[i]}=$(dest ${TAB[0]} $i
)", whats is a val ? A value numeric ?

Comment: The string "val" is the result of the dest function. When assigning a variable, you don't use a `$` on the left-hand side. To assign a value to an array index, you would `TABUTIL[i]=$(dest "${TAB[0]}" $i)` -- note the quotes there, you **must** get into the habit of quoting your variables. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: The error arose because `${TABUTIL[0]}` is empty or unset, so the shell sees `=$(dest ...)` and since that does not look like a variable assignment (no variable on the left-hand side), it is handled as a command, and you get the command not found error